# Очистка данных при обновлении приложения (Android)

Tags: android, база-данных, кэширование

Как можно удалить все сохраненные ранее SharedPreferences и SQLite Database при обновлении приложения с PlayMarket? Формат сохраненных данных изменился в новой версии, и при установке поверх некоторых из старых версий приложение вылетает, а при чистой установке проблем не наблюдается. Заставить пользователей вручную удалять приложение, а потом устанавливать по-новой, я не могу.

Comment: SharedPreferences при добавлении или удалении данных не вылетает. А SQL нужно было делать так, что бы база обновлялась при переустановке, и ничего вылетать не будет. Меняется версия файла базы данных, дописываются новые поля или удаляются, и ничего не вылетает. Изучите вопрос добавления полей без удаления базы

Comment: Я знаком с миграциями, но у меня нет возможности написать правильный скрипт, потому что знаю о проблеме только из отзывов и отчета об ошибках. Нет на руках устройства с проблемой. Поэтому хотелось бы просто очистить базу, чтобы потом обновить ее из интернета в процессе работы приложения

Comment: Это неправильно. Если вы не умеете работать в среде разработки, что бы ошибок не было, надо учиться. И учиться воспроизводить ошибки у себя

Answer (score 0):

Актуально только если исползуется Room

С базой проблема решается просто. Повышаете @Database(version = {цифра больше чем на проде}). Найдите место инициализации базы, вроде:

```
val builder = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "database.db")
```

и добавьте строчку

```
builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
```

Произойдет следующее: в случаи ошибки миграции, схема базы перезапишется на новую без вылетов.

С SharedPreferences чуть сложнее, вам нужно знать имена файлов, которые вы хотите удалить. Но обычно их и не нужно удалять, используйте свои, новые.

Comment: Да, у меня уже так сделано. Если я правильно понял - то в случае ошибки старая база просто затрется? Или затрется только отдельная таблица?